# Amplying hallsensor Output

Tags: arduino, sensor, hall-effect

I am planning to use [Hall sensor](http://www.techpowerelectronics.com/catalogue-techpower/media/wysiwyg/pdf/BJHCS-LSP-25A.pdf).I am trying to measure The high DC current up to 20A .Is any can share link to Build ampilfied network to amplify hall out put and feed back to Arduino.

And another problem i am facing here is Determining out put Whether it is pulse output or analog.

Answer (score 2):

The output of this sensor is 0.5V to 4.5V for -20A to +20A so I don't think you need or want any amplification.

Comment: In data sheet no where mentioned that output is 0.5v to 4.5V . they mentioned in data sheet VO with equation.i.e means it analog voltage

Comment: Well, I didn't pull it out of ... the equation tells you that, \$V_{OE}\$ is "sort of" defined as 2.5V nominal (give or take 15mV) by the inappropriate section "ACCURACY DYNAMIC PERFORMANCE", then you use the equation inappropriately called "Rated output voltage VO (V)". It's **not** a great datasheet. The **sampling resistor** and **secondary coil turns** appear to be copied from some other product (a current transformer) and do not apply to this device (since it's Hall type and works down to DC). Or maybe it's the feedback coil for the Hall, but it's not a secondary then.

Comment: ok.  i have seen lots of hall sensor data sheet by now.Usually they do amplifying .1) why amplification needed. 2) Which amplying circuit should be used.

Comment: This particular product you referenced in this question has the appropriate circuit built in, so the work is done for you. Raw Hall sensors provide only a small voltage so there is amplification, and it's a feedback circuit that nulls the Hall sensor to avoid excessive nonlinearity. It's more of a control system than an amplifier, really.

Comment: [link](http://www.electrohms.com/data_pdf/HA025T01_01.pdf). Here i am attaching another link. Is analog output.One question always in my mind when to go with amplification for better output

Comment: If your sensor output (over the desired range) matches your ADC input, you don't need amplification. You might want some filtering, but that is **really** another question.